# Using Gmail Api with Iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsurlconnection

I am creating an app that needs to connect to the Gmail server and fetch the inbox emails and sort them out and store them in core data modal. I have no idea on how I could integrate this gmail into my app. Is there api available in  Gmail, that would work with NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that lets me read the email in the form of atom feed,
requesting to the following url could fetch my email in XML format :

```
 https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom
```

Thank you for your suggestion. Helped me lot !

Comment: Remember that if you are placing these requests through a proxy, you can run the risk of logging those usernames and passwords

Comment: So, how can I be secure of not logging credentials. How about using POP/IMAP access. How can I achieve those?

Comment: I would suggest using OAuth or OpenId if they are allowed in this scheme.

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider using POP or IMAP?
2. Gmail offers RSS feeds for Inboxes http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=18218

I don't think there's a Gmail API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Gmail API now:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/